# How to get knockout loop inside another loop while binding data to html

Tags: knockout.js

I am getting json data as output and binding in knockout.

Json Data

```
{
"frequency": [
    {
        "freqid": "2",
        "freqname": "Monthly",
        "date": [
            "1-02-2014",
            "7-02-2014",
            "10-02-2013",
            "28-03-2013"
        ],
        "isindtl1": {
            "mkttp": "0",
            "mktdesc": "",
            "odpid": "",
            "srno": "1",
            "oclientid": "",
            "setlno": "",
            "txnqty": "200.000",
            "txndesc": "Rights Issue",
            "osetlno": "",
            "dorc": "D",
            "txnrefno": "1001233225",
            "txndt": "20130924"
        },
        "ny": "6.0",
        "ty": "0"
    },
    {
        "freqid": "3",
        "freqname": "Quarterly",
        "date": [
            "1-02-2014",
            "7-02-2014",
            "10-02-2013",
            "28-03-2013"
        ],

        "ny": "4.0",
        "ty": "0"
    }
]
}
```

This is the valid json and i am looping for frequency in my html using knockout binding and displaying the data like this.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: FreqList">
              <div data-bind="text:freqname"></div>
</div>
```

It is working but i  also want to loop `date` inside this loop like below so that for every frequency i can get the date which is in loop.

Also i want to loop for `isindtl1` tag  and want all value for this.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: FreqList">
                  <div data-bind="text:freqname"></div>
                  <span  data-bind="foreach: date"></span>
                   <span  data-bind="foreach: isindtl1">
                          <span  data-bind="text: txnissue"></span>
                   </span>
    </div>
```

How to do this with knockout.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div data-bind="foreach: FreqList">
 <div data-bind="text:freqname"></div>
  <!-- ko foreach:  $data.date -->
     <span  data-bind="text: $data"></span>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Prints the following

```
Monthly
1-02-2014 7-02-2014 10-02-2013 28-03-2013
Quarterly
1-02-2014 7-02-2014 10-02-2013 28-03-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look over here Updated Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pratbhoir/Hnug4/17/

You cant apply foreach to that isindtl cuz they dont have same values, its not array. So, you have to acces values individually

```
<div data-bind="foreach: freqList">
    <div data-bind="text:freqname"></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach:date"> <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>,</div>
    <div>mkttp: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.mkttp"> </span></div>
    <div>mktdesc: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.mktdesc"> </span></div>
    <div>odpid: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.odpid"> </span></div>
    <div>srno: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.srno"> </span></div>
    <div>oclientid: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.oclientid"> </span></div>
    <div>setlno: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.setlno"> </span></div>
    <div>txnqty: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.txnqty"> </span></div>
    <div>txndesc: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.txndesc"> </span></div>
    <div>osetlno: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.osetlno"> </span></div>
    <div>dorc: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.dorc"> </span></div>
    <div>txnrefno: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.txnrefno"> </span></div>
    <div>txndt: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.txndt"> </span></div>
    <div>ny: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.ny"> </span></div>
    <div>ty: <span data-bind="text: isindtl1.ty"> </span></div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Please mark this as a answer, if it helps you

Comment: I got this and works for me..but if isindt1 is multiple time then how will i loop it like date.